Python: how to match a string "TEXT" to a variable with the same name within a class such as self.TEXT
Considering this code: I was trying to match the self.ingredients [strings] with the other self.variables with the same name as follows.
class CoffeeMachine:

    def __init__(self):
        self.water = 400
        self.coffee = 45
        self.milk = 300
        self.ingredients = ['water', 'coffee', 'milk']

But of course I get an attribute error since this Class has no such attribute " i ". Any idea how to fix this?
for i in self.ingredients:
    self.i = ...

Thanks a lot in advance,

setattr(self, i, ...)

But if you need to access them dynamically, why not just use a dictionary?

You should be using a list
self.ingredients = {'water': 400, 'coffee': 45, 'milk': 300}
After, you can set the values for each key in the dictionary with a different value

@David This is a dict, not a list.

@AndrewYim good point - I tried correcting my typo but I cant edit a comment
